# What happens when there is more minted tokens than collateral?

Tags: mint

A bit of a very noob question but I am confused. Let's say that you deposit a $1000 worth of a certain token into a synthetic asset (Which gives you $500 synthetic usd) and you manage to double it. How does the project pay you back ?. lets say you deposit $2k eth into a stablecoin project and you are given %50 in usd and you triple that amount(1k-3k). what happens in this case ?.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got your question fully.

But if you buy a real stablecoin then the coin is stable against the asset that covers the coin (like Thether against the US dollar) and you should not be able to triple your investment. If 1 unit of the stablecoin is covered by 1 Dollar and the stablecoin would double in worth, then of course 1 unit of the stablecoin would be covered by only 50 cent.

If you buy coins that are not stable then everthing else is just your hope and your believe. If you buy an asset for 500 dollars and it tripples its value, then you will not get this value from the project but from the next buyer who buys it on an exchange from you. The same happens if the value drops down to the half of your purchase price. There is nobody who covers your lost.

Maybe a coin is covered by US dollar and it is not stable against the US dollar, then there maybe a floor price that is guaranteed. But if you buy the coin above the floor price the rest is your risk.

Whatever coin or asset: It is individual - there are no general rules. Read the terms & conditions carefully. If you have the expertise, then check the smart contracts. But this is often difficult because some smart contracts are coded very complex. Everything that may be written in the term & conditions but is not coded in the smart contracts cannot be guaranteed by the blockchains mechanisms.

For example there are wild speculations where the dollars are deposited that cover the Theter. What we know - the deposit of the dollars is not controlled by the smart contracts. Thus the deposit of the dollars is out of the control of the blockchain. You have to trust the company behind the Thether (and this, by the way, has nothing to do with decentralizing)